# CSS one image out of 5 not aligned as the rest

Tags: css, html

I have 4 smaller (320x312 px) images and one larger rectangular image (541x602 px). My goal is to place 2 smaller images on each side of the larger one. The 3 smaller are places as i need, but the last one (lower left corner) is totally out of place, located way lower than needed. The code is exactly the same and i cant lift it with padding. I created an illustration.

Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/QWStS/

[image]

I need the purple shape to be under the black, and aligned with the blue to its right.

this is the code:

HTML5

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="box-image">
         <img src="1.png">
     </div>

     <div class="box-image">
         <img src="3.png">
     </div>

     <div class="box-image">
         <img src="4.png">
     </div>

     <div class="box-image">
         <img src="5.png">
     </div>

     <div class="box-image">
         <img src="2.png">
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.container .box-image {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's all the relevant CSS? That code will only show each image in-line, one after the other. At least for us, since we don't have access to the .png files you are using.

Comment: Yes that is it. Setting width limit pushes the images in the place i illustrated. Should i upload the images?

Comment: JSfiddle required: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: JSfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/QWStS/

Comment: This is the expected behavior for floats.  http://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Btqup

Does not require floats, and would be quite flexible if I hadn't used pixels to measure.

Explanation: There are three columns (div.large). In the first and third column, there are small boxes (div.smallbox) that are half the width, minus a little for padding. The code is pretty self-explanatory, though - check it out.

Comment: thanks, that really helped and worked for me. how can i lift the larger image a bit up? i notice that if i try to access its properties by:
div#big.large{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
nothing happens.

Comment: thanks, i must have done something wrong, it really works. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should create 3 columns : in the first column you can put two small images, in the second put the large image and finally, put two small images in the last column. Then, **apply a width and float: left** on each column.

Be careful, the total width of the three columns must be lower than your container's width.